# ModelMap and @Controller in spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

1. Is there something like ModelMap in spring webflow ?
2. In spring webflow I would like to put multiple objects into map under different keys
   and then display them in jsp page. How should I do it ?
3. How can I get @Controller functionality in spring webflow - preparing data for jsp page?

Comment: Check this example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342621/web-flow-add-model-attribute-for-binding-with-form-values/23344985#23344985

DispatcherServlet forwards the requests to "ClassForThisFlow" class to process each of your request. 
Also, you can use any data type(map, list, etc.,) in the form "Client". Depending on you requirement, you can put this form in View scope or flow scope and use this through that flow cycle.

Answer (score 0):

1.) More read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html)

**ModelMap subclasses LinkedHashMap**.

addAttribute can be called with just a value, and the map key is then inferred from the type.

The `addAttribute` methods all return the ModelMap, so you can chain method called together, e.g. `modelMap.addAttribute('x', x).addAttribute('y',y)`

The `addAttribute` methods checks that the values aren't null

The generic type of ModelMap is fixed at *`Map<String, Object>`*, which is the only one that makes sense for a view model.

2.) Need to access ModelMap values through expression language

// At controller layer

```
modelMap.put("result",myResult);
```

/At Jsp layer

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h1>{result}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

3.) The **@Controller** annotation is used to mark any java class as a controller class.
Also you can add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` for enabling the Spring MVC annotations.

detailed information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: Ankur-Singhal how can I access modelMap in spring webflow ? I would like @Controller functionality, but with spring webflow, not regular spring mvc - how is it possible ?