# Is there an easy way to map Form object to Entity Object in Springboot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, swagger

I have created a form object input in rest api in order to avoid mess data when user input in springboot. I wanna know is there a better way to map from Form input to entity class. Note: for me I mapped by set one by one property to entity class.

Here is an example:

## 1. Class for input in swagger

```
public class LoginForm {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    // Getter setter

}
```

## 2. Class that map with database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table_user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

 // Setter Getter

}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342621/web-flow-add-model-attribute-for-binding-with-form-values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ModelMapper

plugin: **compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:1.1.3'**

example: loginForm your request object.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
User user = modelMapper.map(loginForm,User.class)
```